# Apache Sling resource not found when added to /launchpad directory

Tags: apache, exception, resources, sling

Reading manual about Sling http://sling.apache.org/site/46-line-blog.html

added folder blog and blog.html to destination:

```
\launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\
```

but it's couldn't be accessible still from URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/blog/blog.html
```

error:

```
The requested URL /blog/blog.html resulted in an error in org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.defaults.DefaultErrorHandlerServlet.
Request Progress:

      0 (2012-06-14 15:12:32) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2012-06-14 15:12:32) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2012-06-14 15:12:32) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/blog/blog.html
      0 (2012-06-14 15:12:32) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
     12 (2012-06-14 15:12:32) TIMER_END{12,ResourceResolution} URI=/blog/blog.html resolves to Resource=NonExistingResource, path=/blog/blog.html
...
```

Did anybody add content to Sling launchpad directory?

**Update:**

content(blog.html file) was added to local folder there:

```
d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\blog
```

as it was advised in article (as I it understand)

It was done `mvn clean install` from `d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\pom.xml` ,so got structure in target:

```
d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\target\classes\content\blog\blog.html
```

Anyway `http://localhost:8080/blog/blog.html` is not available

**1.** This URL is available:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

it corresponds to local file:

```
d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\index.html
```

**2.** This URL is available also:

```
 http://localhost:8080/sling-test/sling/sling-test.html
```

it corresponds to local file:

```
d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\sling-test\sling\sling-test.html
```

So,the core problem that my custom manually added content is not displayed by Apache Sling server

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "added content to \launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\", the backslashes seem to indicate that you added that content to the filesystem. You'll need to explain more precisely how you "added content" there.

Comment: Bertrand hi,could you,please, see Update section I've added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> content(blog.html file) was added to local folder there:
>
> d:\workspaceSling\sling\launchpad\content\src\main\resources\content\blog
>
> as it was advised in article (as I it understand)

which is not correct, the only file that you need for the tutorial at http://sling.apache.org/site/46-line-blog.html is a script at /apps/blog/blog.esp script *in the content repository*, not in the filesystem. Mounting the repository via WebDAV is one way to create that file, or you can use curl as described in the "Sling in 15 minutes" tutorial mentioned below.

IMO you should be fine if you go back to the tutorial and follow the instructions more closely. Maybe the more basic tutorial at http://sling.apache.org/site/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html would help grasp the Sling basics better.

Comment: Hi Bertrand,thank you for hint.I never used `WebDAV`.I will feedback as soon try it out.